# Word 2016: How can I rename a data source file, without having to recreate the data connection?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-excel-2016, mail-merge, microsoft-word-2016

I have a Word document, that is configured for mail merge.
The data source for the mail merge, is a complicated Excel workbook, containing numerous queries and database connections.

I need to rename the Excel workbook (filename), but I don't want to have to reconfigure the data connection in Word (the tables and queries are complicated, and I'll probably break it).

Is there a simple way for me to change only the filename specified in the data connection, without modifying any other parts of the data connection?

Comment: Are you using Word to edit the document? If there are so many tables and queries, are you not better off using a text editor to mass change variable names?

Comment: if it is docx format, then may be to try to extract xml(s) from it search for all occurrences file name in its contents and replace for new file name, and then pack again. just idea. you can unpack with standard archiver that supports zip archives

Comment: @shibormot I had no idea that was possible. I unpacked it with WinRar, searched the unpacked directory for the workbook filename, found three references across two files, replaced all three references, repacked the zip archive, renamed the zip file to *.docx ... and it worked like a charm! Post this as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Giffyguy glad to help you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is docx format, then it can be done with following way:

1. Extract xml(s)
2. From it search for all occurrences file name in its contents and replace for new file name
3. Then pack again.

You can unpack with standard archiver that supports zip archives